# How to deal with the possibility of multiple list elements having the same names

Tags: r

I have just noticed that it is possible to construct lists in which multiple elements have the same name, for instance:

```
l <- list(a=1, a="a")
```

When element names are used to extract the list elements, the first element matching the name is returned: `l$a` returns `1` without so much as a warning.

I typically extract list elements by name. Now I'm worried that I will accidentally create lists with multiple elements having the same name (for instance by trying to merge lists by a common index), access the wrong list elements, and never know there was a problem.

Every time I use a list, I could test whether it has multiple elements with the same name:

```
length(unique(names(l)))==length(names(l))
```

...but this is cumbersome. Is there a better way to deal with this potential problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'deal'? There's `names(l) <- make.unique(names(l))`...

Comment: What I really want is for `l$a` to fail (or issue a warning) if more than one elements are named `a`. I guess I'd also like an explanation of why repeated names are allowed - it seems like there's little upside and a potentially large downside to allowing them, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: There are several functions in R that return a `list` with automatic names based on the arguments supplied. The arguments may or may not contain duplicates, and thus may or may lead to duplicate names. Rather than break each time such functions are called with duplicates, R assumes that if it matters to you, you'll be prudent enough to handle duplicates explicitly. It wouldn't seem unreasonable to me, though, for `$` raise a warning if called on a list with repeated names. Maybe it's an efficiency thing. As a shorter way to check, you could write `stopifnot(! any(duplicated(names(l))))`

Comment: And example of such a function call leading to duplicate names would be `mapply(rep, c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), 1:4)`. You may not really care about the names in such a case, and it would be annoying to have to catch an error or suppress a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I'd recommend this **at all**, but here's a perhaps less cumbersome way to ensure that you don't extract an element from a list that contains repeated names:

```
## Define a method for `[[` that first checks the list x for repeated names
`[[.CC` <- function(x,i,j,...,exact=TRUE) {
    if(!length(unique(names(x))) == length(names(x))) {
        stop("List contains multiple elements with the same name")
    } else {
        NextMethod()
    }
}

## Write  a function that prepends the class that triggers the method above
CC <- function(X) {
    class(X) <- c("CC", class(X))
    X
}

## Try it out
l <- list(a=1, a="a")
m <- list(a=1, b="a")

CC(l)[["a"]]
# Error in `[[.CC`(CC(l), "a") : 
#   List contains multiple elements with the same name

CC(m)[["a"]]
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - that function supercedes the base `[[` function? Yeah, that's scary.

Comment: Nah, the way I've written it, there's nothing to worry about. There are many methods for `[[`. Do `methods("[[")` to see the ones available in your R session. `[[.CC` will only get used on objects of class `"CC"`, which (because it's a nonsense name) will mean just those objects that you wrap with the function `CC()`.

Comment: `anyDuplicated` would be a clearer (and faster) way of checking for duplicated names.

Comment: @hadley -- Yeah, I thought of that and hesitated since it requires folks to know how things like `if(11)` and `if(0)` are evaluated. That's a good thing to understand, though, so in retrospect, I agree.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I'm not sure I follow, `anyDuplicated` returns a single logical value.

Comment: @hadley -- That's what the name would lead you to believe (and in practice it doesn't make a difference when just wrapped in an `if` clause), but check this out: `anyDuplicated(c(1,2,2,2,3,3))` --> `[1] 3`. (Oddly, I had used it before without noticing this as well). (See also the Value section of `?anyDuplicated` which states, "‘anyDuplicated()’: a non-negative integer (of length one)."

Comment: @hadley -- And they give *you* all the grief about your functions' names. What gives? ;)